# Regarding external-document in FOP

Tags: apache-fop

I am creating pdf file through the XML, XSL and FOP. I want PDF file contents to display external file contents such as word document.
I know for displaying image in PDF we use  but what tag we should to display file contents other than pdf file type.

There's a FOP extension that claims to be able to do this:

jeremias-maerki.ch/development/fop/index.html

Also see xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/extensions.html#external-document

When I used in this way

xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"
             content-type="pdf" src="C:\temp\reports\p2.pdf"/>

I am getting exception as

org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: Error(Unknown location): No element mapping definition found for fox:external-document

Let me know the reason.

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're probably using an old [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop) version which doesn't have the fox:external-document extension, yet. Please upgrade to FOP 1.0 (or at least 0.95).

Answer (score 1):

Change the namespace from:

```
http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions
```

to

```
http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions
```